# Mnesia get all data from field

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have mnesia table:

```
-record(counter, {

                     value,
                      type,
                      tree
                 }).
```

How can i get all data from  this 3 fields?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You just want all the data from a table? Off the top of my head:

`mnesia:transaction(fun()-> qlc:e(mnesia:table(counter)) end).`

The same thing but more efficient:

`mnesia:async_dirty(fun()-> qlc:e(mnesia:table(counter)) end).`

Comment: Yes, i want get all data from table. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 2):

also, faster:
`mnesia:dirty_match_object(#counter{_ = '_'}).`